# Is it a kind of deadlock in the code?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, deadlock

Definitely, second loop will never be executed, but still curious to know whether the following example could be classified as a deadlock or not.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            System.out.print(i + " ");

        Thread.currentThread().join();

        for (int i = 11; i <= 20; i++)
            System.out.print(i + " ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Waiting forever does not make it a deadlock. The current thread isn't blocking any other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not a deadlock.  But you did block your main thread indefinitely.  The [`join` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) blocks until the `Thread` on which it is called dies.

> Waits for this thread to die.

Calling `Thread.currentThread().join();` means that the main thread is waiting for itself to die, which won't happen.

This differs from a deadlock, where two threads each own the lock on separate resources, but each needs the other's locked resource to continue.  That is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a self-deadlock.  "Deadlock" describes a situation where every member of a set of threads is waiting for some other member to do something.

---

More formally,  Imagine a directed graph representing an instant in the life of the process.  Each node in the graph corresponds to a thread in the process, and an arc from A to B means that thread A is blocked until thread B completes some action.

If the graph contains a cycle, then the threads in that cycle are deadlocked.

So the question is, what do you call a cycle of one?  Some of us call it "self deadlock".  You can google for that phrase to find out who we are.

Comment: @Kayaman, I won't disagree with that, but I still think that "deadlock" is an apt description of the reason why it is hung.  In the classic deadlock, A is waiting for B to do something while at the same time B is waiting for A.  You can generalize that (e.g., A waits for B while B waits for C while C waits for A), or you can have a degenerate case (A waits for A.)

Comment: @jameslarge, "deadlock" is a term with a pretty generally accepted meaning in the context of concurrent programming: it is a situation in which *two or more* concurrent actions each prevent one of the others from completing.  That there is a two-action minimal case does not mean that a similar one-action situation still satisfies the definition.  You can apply whatever definitions you want, but if you want to communicate effectively with others then you will stick to the commonly accepted definitions of standard terms.

Comment: @jameslarge, you might consider Googling "deadlock" itself.  All the top hits that speak to the definition of the term in computing context are consistent about the "two or more", from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html) (particularly relevant here) to [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177433%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) to even [the Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deadlock).

Comment: @JohnBollinger, that is why I usually qualify the single-thread case by calling it _self_ deadlock.